# Displaying array in uitableview

Tags: objective-c

I have an array created like this:

```
[currentQuizArrayQuestions insertObject:[quizArrayQuestions objectAtIndex:randomIndex] atIndex:0];
```

How do I access its data to display in the table?

I'm trying this:

```
 NSString *cellValue = [currentQuizArrayQuestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

I know it's wrong, but how do I get to the data array object stored in the `currentQuizArrayQuestions` array.

Comment: Can you explain what you're currently seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. See this tutorial on UITableViews: http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/

That one uses a UITableViewController, but the idea is the same.

Edit:

To use a different array, do the same thing with the cell for row at index path method, changing the array that the cellValues come from according to what you need. Then call [tableView reload]; which will run through cellForRowAtIndexPath with the contents of the new array.

Comment: sorry i should have made it more clear, have implemented all the other methods required and i can get it working from the original array and i can see whats in the new array using nslog but just can't figure how to display it in the cell

Comment: i created an array then randomised and put the new random results into another array thats the array i want to show in my table the objects are in the new array as i can see them using nslog hope its clear .. its been a confusing afternoon!